# WebRTC support and phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, phonegap-plugins, webrtc

I am testing this simple piece of code coupled to an equally simple node.js server script:

```
<script>
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://materiali.c-s-m.it:9090');
connection.onmessage = function (message) { 
    alert(message.data);
   console.log("Got message", message.data);
};
</script>
```

to the objective of inserting it into a phonegap app. When I connect to it by a standard browser it works with Chrome on Windows and on the Windows phone and Android (it shows the pop-up and the access is registered on the server log), but not on the iPhone both with Safari, Chrome and the PhoneGap app.
I have divergent information about WebRTC support on the browsers. Some founts report its support by WebKit integrally, others not at all.
What is the real situation, how may have it working on the iPhone and more importantly on the PhoneGap app for all the platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing Crosswalk by Cordova the service now works both on WindowsPhone and Android by means of the PhoneGap developer app. Unfortunately it does not work on iOS.